# how to export array (array collection) data into an html table or text file

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript, export

Hey all,
I have an array collection of strings and integers (which I have displayed in a data grid) and I am wondering if it is possible to export the array collection into an html table? or even a text file for the user to download

I found some pages that had an export to .xls files but I want to stray away from that for now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can export a DataGrid to an HTML table or a text file.

But you'll have to write your own conversion routine to do so.  If you want the user to download a file, you'll most likely need to send the data back to the server and have that server process it; then send the user a download link.